# Deploy azure key vault secret using arm template gives error

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I want to create secret in my key vault using arm template. But I am getting the following error

Note: The key vault is already created, so its not needed in arm template

My resource to create this looks like below

```
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/secrets",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('azure_keyvault_name'), '/', parameters('secrets_test_name'))]",
        "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
        "location": "centralus",
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
            "attributes": {
                "enabled": true
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": []
    }
```

I get error: "Can not perform requested operation on nested resource. Parent resource 'azure_keyvault_name' not found."

But I dont need parent resource as its already created

what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The error message says that the parent resource, aka your keyvault is not found. Are you sure you're passing the right name ? is it available under the same `centralus` location ?

Comment: are you deploying to right region\subscription\tenant?

Comment: When you execute this ARM template deployment are you deploying it to a different resource group to the one that contains the KeyVault?

Comment: @Leyshon: Yes that was the problem. Thanks for help everyone

Comment: @Leyshon is it mandatory for the KeyVault (KV) and the resource thats trying to insert the secret to be in the same RG? for eg- I could have KV in a global resource group where as storageaccount that I m creating could be in a different RG. Is it still possible to use ARM template to add secrets in to KV in different RG?

Comment: @Sai Did you figure a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was deploying arm template to a resource group which is different form the one which has key vault